# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options'

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I've been getting this error message when I try to run my Azure function v4.

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

This used to work like a week ago, and now it's throwing this error at runtime. Latest changes I did was to update EF Core to version 7. But I guess that's not relevant because that's in a different project, so not related to the function project.

These are the package references in my function project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Has anyone else got it or any idea how to resolve it?

Tried removing all the Nuget packages and installing them. That didn't work.
I can see the Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll (v7) in the debug folder as well. Not sure why the runtime complains about it.

I recently updated to VS 2022 Version 17.4.1. Maybe that's the issue here?

Comment: Post the `<PackageReference>` elements from your `.csproj` - don't post a screenshot of the NuGet UI - which also doesn't show that you have `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` added anyway...

Comment: @Dai added the package references as well.

Comment: [don't post pictures of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: I hope everything is in order now..

Comment: The same packages you have given is working fine in .NET 6 AF project https://i.imgur.com/lWiCJA2.png. And it is working fine in .NET 7 isolated when I remove Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (last package). https://i.imgur.com/WnU8irc.png .

Comment: .Net 7 is not available yet. So, please update to .NET 7 isolated and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja. I actually started with .NET 6 and switched to .NET 7. Now I've switched back to .NET 6. But still not seems to be working :(

Comment: In .Net 6 try to rebuild and reinstall all nuget packages as it is working fine in .Net 6

Comment: I seems to be getting into the same situation no matter what I try :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249692/discussion-between-thusitha-and-rithwikbojja).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment,I have observed that the same packages you have given is working fine in .NET 6 Azure functions project

[image]

And it is working fine in .NET 7 isolated when I remove `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` (last package).

[image]

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified

As discussed in comments Try to degrade

`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` nuget package to Version="6.0.0". Try to revert back to older versions

Comment: In addition to this, I've reverted most of the version 7+ packages which I upgraded. That was including EF Core 7.0.0..

Comment: But I am targeting to upgrade EF 7.0.0. What shall I do ?

Facing the same error

Comment: I found per [this thread on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2304) that it sometimes takes a few weeks for MS to iron out issues with the packages between EF, Functions and probably some other cases. This however has been a few months already... `Logging.Abstratctions` works, `DependencyInjection` works on v7 packages. Is this still the issue with Functions and the `Configuration.Abstractions` package or is it some other issue? Is there an issue to track for an ETA on fixes?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with identical symptoms. It turns out that the cause, in my case, was the latest `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations` package. I was using `v7.0.0` and downgrading to the previous version `v6.0.0` solved the problem.

Here is my project file for what it's worth:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>True</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <AnalysisLevel>preview-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove=".gitignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Thanks @RithwikBojja for your help and pointer...

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen after you have upgraded your Azure Functions project to .NET 7, but have not migrated your code to follow the isolated model. .NET 7 does not at this time support the in-process model, so you will need to migrate your Functions project (9/12/2023).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net7

Comment: I also got this error with 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions' dependency. after migrating to the isolated model worked!